# etree incomplete child.text

Tags: python, xml, lxml, elementtree

I'm having a trouble when I want to access the text content of a very long XML element.
I'm using the xml.etree library.

The size of the xml element I want to parse is ~ 400 000 characters and I only get 
~ 30 000 characters when I do this :

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.iterparse(xml_document, events=['start','end'])

for action, element in context:
    if element.tag.endswith('tag_name'):
        if action=="start":
            result = element.text
```

Does anyone know how to make sure etree fully reads the text of an element ?

Thank you

Comment: The underlying sax doesn't guarantee that large texts are delivered in one event. So I assume etree doesn't gather alle the events here. You might consider using your own sax-based parser to filter your data, collecting all character-events. Here you can read on the exact behavior: https://mail.python.org/pipermail/xml-sig/2005-January/010838.html It explicitly states that the event-based parsing can only be used to inspect attributes reliably.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I finally found an answer to my own question ...

Just use the "end" event instead of "start" if you want to be sure etree reads all the text content of a tag :

```
from lxml import etree

context = etree.iterparse(xml_document, events=['end'])

for action, element in context:
    if element.tag.endswith('tag_name'):
        if action=="end":
            result = element.text
```